# c++ различие операторов?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, чем  отличаются данные фрагменты кода

```
if (sym == L'#') State = state::started;
                    continue;
```

И

```
if (sym = L'1')
    {
        State = state::s1;
        start = i;
    }
```

Почему там два ==, а тут одно =

Comment: `==` только сравнивает, `=`  присваивает sym значение L'1', и если это значение true (т.е. значение sym, приведённой к числу >0), то выполняет код

Comment: "Тут одно" просто потому, что автор кода сделал опечатку. Должно быть `==` и там, и там.

Comment: Я не делаю опечатку

Comment: Как уже сказал Александр, `==` проверяет операнды на равенство, а `=` присвоит значение правого операнда левому и вернет его, но от себя я добавлю, что это не всегда опечатка! В некоторых случаях можно объединить присваивание и проверку условия, хотя многие разработчики или принципиально так не делают, или договариваются ставить искусственно пару скобок или писать комментарий в коде. Так можно делать не только в условных конструкциях, а где угодно, но я рекомендую не делать это без четкого понимания того, как оно работает, а то можно получить баг: `char a; f(a = -1);` а будет `f(255);`